# EF Core, Should I add foreign key Id in class?

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

I read some tutorials from different site, some add foreign key Id and some don't and other add virtual.

For example:

```
class Class
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public Class class { get; set; }
}
```

Here in the `Student` class, some using virtual on `Class` and some using `ClassId` inside the `Student` class.

What is the best practice for this? I am using EF Core 3 with .NET Core 3.1 (latest one)

Comment: Tip: see what happens when you use one (look at the generated database code) and compare it to the database code that's generated when you don't use one.

Comment: Also, `Id` is a bad name for an identity property because in different contexts it's ambiguous as to what it refers to - it's best to use `Student.StudentId` and `Class.ClassId` instead.

Comment: Foreignkey are db, so add if 1) you need to reinforce constraint in the db, 2) if you need navigation in for code otherwise, in my opinion not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern is called "[Shadow-property](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/shadow-property.aspx)". Let's say we want to get all `Students` by a `ClassId`.

With `Shadow Property`, 2 options to access data:

```
context.Classes.Include(x => x.Students).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == classId)?.Students;

//we have to know the name of foreign key from db.
context.Students.Where(x => EF.Property<int>(x, "ClassId") == classId).ToList();
```

With explicit Foreign Key, the code is:

```
context.Students.Where(x => x.ClassId == classId).ToList();
```

The 2nd & 3rd code avoid a `join`, looks better performance. but which one is best of 2 styles? it really depends on project and coding-style preference.

although the 2nd style is easy to setup:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Add the shadow property to the model
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .Property<int>("ClassId");

        // Use the shadow property as a foreign key
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Class)
            .WithMany(b => b.Students)
            .HasForeignKey("ClassId");
    }
}
```

Here are 2 references:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand now and just knew it called shadow property.

Answer (score 0):

*In the context of EF, marking a property as virtual allows EF to use lazy loading to load it. For lazy loading to work EF has to create a proxy object that overrides your virtual properties with an implementation that loads the referenced entity when it is first accessed. If you don't mark the property as virtual then lazy loading won't work with it.*

For web applications, maybe it's better not to use lazy-loading because lazy-loading can be pulling a huge amount of data.

Assuming you want to generate your database model/relations from your objects/classes (code-first migrations with EF core), the most important part is your entities' mapping configurations (either with annotations on your model properties, or using Fluent API).

If you don't have any specific requirements regarding your "Id" property format, just set it to be generated by the database.

In your case, I would configure it the following way:

```
class Class
{
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public Class class { get; set; }
}
```

And, one way to configure your mappings with Fluent API could be something like:

```
public class StudentConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Student> builder)
    {
        builder
             .HasKey(s => s.StudentId);

        builder
            .Property(s => s.StudentId)
            .UseIdentityColumn();

        builder
            .Property(c => c.StudentName)
            .HasMaxLength(<studentName_maxLength>);

        builder
            .HasOne(s => s.Class)
            .WithMany(c => c.Students)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.ClassId);

        builder
            .ToTable("Student");
    }
}

public class ClassConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Class>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Class> builder)
    {
        builder
             .HasKey(c => c.ClassId);

        builder
            .Property(c => c.ClassId)
            .UseIdentityColumn();   

        builder
            .Property(c => c.ClassName)
            .HasMaxLength(<className_maxLength>);

        builder
            .HasMany(c => c.Students)
            .WithOne(s => s.Class);

        builder
            .ToTable("Class");
    }
}
```

More details regarding configuring Fluent API one-to-many mappings can be found [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration)